# Outbound Azure VM Internet Connectivity

Tags: networking, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, azure

I have a virtual network set up in Windows Azure that contains several servers in an Active Directory domain. The domain computers are unable to access the Internet.

However, the internet is directly accessible from the domain controller. When I attempt to visit an external site from the other Windows Server 2008 R2 domain members, the page fails to load.

The following behavior is also observed on the domain members:

- I can perform an `nslookup` on "google.com" and receive the proper IP addresses from the DNS server.
- I can access websites hosted by other machines within the virtual network (and the same AD domain) via the browser.
- When the server has the same IP address, subnet mask, and default gateway set via DHCP (instead of statically), the internet connection works.

Based on above, I am ruling out a DNS or a Windows Firewall issue. The browser also seems to be working fine also. But I am at a loss to determine the issue.

**Why is my VM unable to access the internet?**

Comment: Do the VM's have their default gateway configured correctly?

Comment: Yes - it is the same as the domain controller. Also, please see edit above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my own issue. The issue was related to the servers being set with static IP addresses. Azure VMs must have their IP addresses set by the Azure DHCP, which respects the subnet and virtual network address spaces.

More information can be found here:
[Setting up DNS within an Azure Virtual Network](https://serverfault.com/questions/483253/seting-up-dns-within-an-azure-virtual-network)

Comment: And it might not only be outbound connectivity that relies on this.  I had a VM that was externally accessible on a couple of endpoints last night but was unreachable this morning.  (I could still remote into and in via another machine on the virtual network.)  I'd tried reconfiguring / creating endpoints via the management console and though they created okay, I still had no connectivity.   Setting the server back to DHCP sorted things immediately.